# Heroku basic http request

Tags: javascript, http, heroku, get, xmlhttprequest

I am a beginner and been playing around with some js code.
First I would like to know what this line of code exactly does. Let's assume n is some variable. My understanding was, that it sends a http request to herokuapp with the data of interest "n". How is that data incorporated?

```
const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
const url='https://myapp.herokuapp.com/?data='+n;
Http.open("GET", url);
Http.send();
```

What is the most simple way to accept and log the data n in my heroku app?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The code above sends a HTTP GET request to the application running at `myapp.herokuapp.com` passing a parameter called `data` with whatever value the variable `n` holds.

On Heroku typically you deploy an application (service) than can listen and process HTTP requests. You can use any language (JS, Python, Java, etc..) since they all are suitable to implement a web service.
Using NodeJS you would do something like:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
 const data = req.query.data // grab parameter
 console.log(`Value of data is ${data}`);
 res
  .status(200)
  .send('Ok')
  .end();
});

// Start the server
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`App listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Checkout [NodeJS on Heroku](https://medium.com/geekculture/deploy-node-applications-on-heroku-a89ed51e0a34) to see how you setup and deploy a NodeJS application.